# How to create compressed Zip archive using ZipOutputStream so that method getSize() of ZipEntry returns correct size?

Tags: java, java-8, zip, zipinputstream, zipoutputstream

Consider the code example that put a single file `test_file.pdf` into zip archive `test.zip` and then read this archive:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File infile = new File("test_file.pdf");
        try (
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(infile);
                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.zip"));
        ) {
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("data");
            entry.setSize(infile.length());

            zos.putNextEntry(entry);
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) >= 0)
            {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
                ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(new File("test.zip"))));
        ) {
            ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
            System.out.println("Entry size: " + entry.getSize());
            zis.closeEntry();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Output:
`Entry size: -1`

But if create uncompressed zip archive (method `ZipEntry.STORED`), getSize() returns correct size:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File infile = new File("test_file.pdf");
        try (
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(infile);
                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.zip"));
        ) {
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
            try (
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(infile));
             ) {
                crc.reset();
                while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    crc.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("data");
            entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED);
            entry.setCompressedSize(infile.length());
            entry.setSize(infile.length());
            entry.setCrc(crc.getValue());

            zos.putNextEntry(entry);
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) >= 0)
            {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
                ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(new File("test.zip"))));
        ) {
            ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
            System.out.println("Entry size: " + entry.getSize());
            zis.closeEntry();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Output (for example but correct):
`Entry size: 9223192`

Compressed zip archives with correct `entry.getSize()` exists (e.g. zip archives by Ark program).

So **question**: how to create **compressed** (`ZipEntry.DEFLATED` or another if exists) zip archive that returns correct size of the entry using only the standard libraries?

I tried [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169370/why-zipinputstream-cant-read-the-output-of-zipoutputstream) but it also does not work:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File infile = new File("test_file.pdf");
        try (
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(infile);
                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.zip"));
        ) {
            int bytesRead;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("data");
            entry.setSize(infile.length());

            zos.putNextEntry(entry);
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) >= 0)
            {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            zos.closeEntry();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (
                ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(new File("test.zip"))));
        ) {
            ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
            zis.read(buffer);
            System.out.println("Entry size: " + entry.getSize());
            zis.closeEntry();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Output:
`Entry size: -1`

Comment: It seems that `ZipOutputStream` isn’t capable of storing the uncompressed size unless you provide the expected compressed size and crc as well. Most likely because you can only have either, all three values or none, and it can’t write the evaluated values on the fly as it can’t rewind an `OutputStream` back to the header after writing the data…

Comment: @Holger Then let I compressed file to temporary zip  archive. Now how to compute **compressed** size of a single file in archive?

Comment: I tried use ```DeflaterOutputStream``` to create compressed file ```File tempCompressedFile```. So question: how to get only size of compressed file without size of header? E.g. now  ```tempCompressedFile.length()``` minus expected size is often (or always) ```122``` bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only set the uncompressed size if you also set the CRC and compressed size as well. Since these information are stored before in a header before the actual data and `ZipOutputStream` can’t rewind arbitrary `OutputStream`s, it can’t calculate these values while writing and store them afterwards (but it will calculate them for verifying the provided values).

Here is a solution for calculating the values in one pass before the writing. It utilizes the fact that you can rewind a stream if it is backed by a file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File infile  = new File("test_file.pdf");
    File outfile = new File("test.zip");
    try (FileInputStream  fis = new FileInputStream(infile);
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
         ZipOutputStream  zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos) ) {

        byte[]  buffer = new byte[1024];
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("data");
        precalc(entry, fis.getChannel());
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        for(int bytesRead; (bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) >= 0; )
            zos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        zos.closeEntry();
    }

    try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(outfile);
        ZipInputStream  zis = new ZipInputStream(fin) ) {

        ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
        System.out.println("Entry size: " + entry.getSize());
        System.out.println("Compressed size: " + entry.getCompressedSize());
        System.out.println("CRC: " + entry.getCrc());
        zis.closeEntry();
    }
}

private static void precalc(ZipEntry entry, FileChannel fch) throws IOException {
    long uncompressed = fch.size();
    int method = entry.getMethod();
    CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
    Deflater def;
    byte[] drain;
    if(method != ZipEntry.STORED) {
        def   = new Deflater(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, true);
        drain = new byte[1024];
    }
    else {
        def   = null;
        drain = null;
    }
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate((int)Math.min(uncompressed, 4096));
    for(int bytesRead; (bytesRead = fch.read(buf)) != -1; buf.clear()) {
        crc.update(buf.array(), buf.arrayOffset(), bytesRead);
        if(def!=null) {
            def.setInput(buf.array(), buf.arrayOffset(), bytesRead);
            while(!def.needsInput()) def.deflate(drain, 0, drain.length);
        }
    }
    entry.setSize(uncompressed);
    if(def!=null) {
        def.finish();
        while(!def.finished()) def.deflate(drain, 0, drain.length);
        entry.setCompressedSize(def.getBytesWritten());
    }
    entry.setCrc(crc.getValue());
    fch.position(0);
}
```

It handles both, uncompressed and compressed entries, but unfortunately, only with the default compression level as `ZipOutputStream` has no method for querying the current level. So if you change the compression level you have to keep the precalc code in sync. Alternatively, you could move the logic into a subclass of `ZipOutputStream` and use the same [`Deflater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/DeflaterOutputStream.html#def) so it will automatically have the same configuration.

A solution working with arbitrary source input streams would require buffering of the entire entry data.

Comment: Thanks. And what does  compression level=```-1```  mean in ```Deflater``` constructor? Documentation says only about values 0-9.

Comment: `-1` means [`DEFAULT_COMPRESSION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.zip.Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION). When I looked at [`ZipOutputStream.setLevel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#setLevel-int-), its documentation says “The default setting is DEFAULT_COMPRESSION” but doesn’t link to it, so I didn’t know where the constant is defined. As I know now, I have changed the code to cleanly use the named constant.

Answer (score -1):

A simple and elegant workaround is to write the `ZipEntry` to a temporary `ZipOutputStream` first. This is what the `updateEntry` method of the following code does. When the method has been called, the `ZipEntry` knows the size, compressed size and CRC, without having to calculate them explicitly. When it is written to the target `ZipOutputStream`, it will correctly write the values.

Original answer:

---

dirty but fast

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "source.txt" );
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( "result.zip" );
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream( fos );

    byte[] buf = new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(buf);
    ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry( "source.txt" );

    updateEntry(e, buf);

    zos.putNextEntry(e);
    zos.write(buf);
    zos.closeEntry();

    zos.close();
}

private static void updateEntry(ZipEntry entry, byte[] buffer) throws IOException
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream( bos );
    zos.putNextEntry(entry);
    zos.write(buffer);
    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();
    bos.close();
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I edited this answer because it is in my opinion a 'hidden gem' which has not received the attention it deserves.

Comment: @alain it’s indeed not so bad, as long as the `Deflater` configuration is not changed. It’s what I meant in my answer with “*A solution working with arbitrary source input streams would require buffering of the entire entry data*”. But it should use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html). Then, we can make it really shine by adapting to recent JDKs, Java 9: `byte[] buf = fis.readAllBytes();` and Java 11: `ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(OutputStream.nullOutputStream());` instead of using `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: @Holger, thanks for your comment. My use case is a zip file with a few tiny config files for a device. What I liked about this is the simplicity. I used try-with-resources in my code, but didn't want to change the code of this answer, it could be too much change for an edit of someone elses answer.