# How to create a streaming data header with java.util.zip

Tags: java, zip

I am trying to recreate zip files compatible with a legacy program (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147396/differences-java-util-zip-and-windows-default-zip-utility)).

One of the differences between the files is the presence of `STREAMING DATA HEADERS` which are absent from the zip file created by Java.

How can I implement this structure using Java ?